# Android client error with returning valid JSON from Django server

Tags: android, django, json

I am hoping someone might be able to help me out.

I have a Django server that is returning JSON to an iOS application. On the Django server, we are using

```
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(session_dict),mime_type)
```

to return the JSON to the client as (via Wireshark)

2f
{"session": "bcb493fb21ae8fcd9152e1924b3e5d9a"}
0

This response is somehow valid to the iOS application able to be parsed by the iOS JSON client libraries. This does not look like valid Json to me so I am surprised it works.

However, if I use the following in Android, I get an error:

Value session of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject.

```
jsonObjSend.put("username", strUserName);
                jsonObjSend.put("password", strPassword);

                 Add a nested JSONObject (e.g. for header information)
                JSONObject header = new JSONObject();
                header.put("deviceType","Android"); // Device type
                header.put("deviceVersion","2.0"); // Device OS version
                header.put("language", "es-es");
                jsonObjSend.put("header", header);

                // Output the JSON object we're sending to Logcat:
                Log.i(TAG, jsonObjSend.toString(2));

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



            try {
                // Send the HttpPostRequest and receive a JSONObject in return
                JSONObject jsonObjRecv = HttpClient.SendHttpPost(URL, jsonObjSend);
                String sessionId = jsonObjRecv.getString("session");
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you,

Greg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your HttpClient.sendHttpPost method return a JSONObject? Not sure if it parses the response body from the HTTP POST into a JSONObject automatically. If it doesn't, then you would have to do that using the [JSONTokener](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONTokener.html) or use a library like Gson.

Comment: Thanks I made a couple of dumb mistakes in the Http client. I fixed the class to send the right encoding and the stream returned the correct json strings.

Answer (score 0):

google's GSON  may be a better choice you can convert an instance to json string directly such as

```
User user =new User("tom","12");
Gson gson =new Gson();
json=gson.toJson(user);
```